# Why do I have /Volumes/Storage Drive?

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, disk-utility

In Terminal, I noticed I have `/Volumes/Storage Drive`. On my mac, I have no drive named `Storage Drive`. Furthermore, no `Storage Drive` appears in Finder or Disk Utility. When I `cd` inside `Storage Drive` and `ls -a`, it is empty.

What is this `/Volumes/Storage Drive`? Why is it not appearing in Finder or Disk Utility? Can I safely get rid of it?

The output of `df` does not show the `/Volumes/Storage Drive`:

```
jerzy@jerzys-mbp $ df
Filesystem                                                 512-blocks      Used  Available Capacity  iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2                                                467182912 392156184   74514728    85% 49083521    9314341   84%   /
devfs                                                             419       419          0   100%      725          0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s2                                               1464477344 296803024 1167674320    21% 37100376  145959290   20%   /Volumes/Storage
map -hosts                                                          0         0          0   100%        0          0  100%   /net
map auto_home                                                       0         0          0   100%        0          0  100%   /home
localhost:/-ZOSLTsDfGt2NKFW5Q-SUw                           467182912 467182912          0   100%        0          0  100%   /Volumes/MobileBackups
//jerzy@Jerzy%E2%80%99s%20Mac%20mini._smb._tcp.local/jerzy  975093952  72910968  902182984     8%        0 18446744073709551615    0%   /Volumes/jerzy
```

Here is the output of `diskutil list`:

```
jerzy@jerzys-mbp:/Volumes|⇒  diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *240.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Primary                 239.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *750.2 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Storage                 749.8 GB   disk1s2
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *16.0 MB    disk2
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Flash Player            16.0 MB    disk2s2
```

If it helps to know this: I have a 250GB SSD (mounted to `/`), and a 750GB HDD (mounted to `/Storage`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are, it's just a folder created randomly by some app or another at some point to use as a [mount point](http://www.linfo.org/mount_point.html) and it was never deleted. It should be perfectly safe to `rm -rf` it, especially if it is empty.

*Note: If you `rm -rf` in `/Volumes`, make sure you specify which directory  to operate on (i.e. DON'T JUST `rm -rf /Volumes`!) otherwise you will delete everything on every mounted disk, including your root drive (granted, it will throw permissions errors before doing anything to your OS first but still). Try to delete things in Finder if you’re not sure of your `rm` skills or if you don’t have a backup or time now to restore from that backup.*

Comment: rm -d would be safer to remove an empty directory, which should be the case for a mount point.

Answer (score -1):

Adobe did this perhaps, while updating Flash Player or playing online games which using Flash.